# GET-запрос с параметрами не видемыми в URL

Tags: javascript, html, django

Имеется GET-запрос, но при загрузке страницы в URL не видно параметров. Как так происходит? Что это такое и где почитать подробно?

---

Добавил пример кода GET-запроса:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="window.open("{% url 'sklad' %}", '_blank')">
    Склад
</button>
```

Склад прописан в URL-ах:

`url(r'^azmiestsklad/sklad/$', mySklad.as_view() name='sklad')`

Как я понимаю, происходит GET-запрос, но при этом URL страницы дополнительно не содержит имен параметров.

Comment: а можно код какой-то или чего? может там POST запрос, или все таки GET?

Comment: А может и не было параметров?

Comment: @Олександр добавил пример кода

Comment: @vp_arth я новичок в этом, но знаю, что параметры как-то передаются и происходит это GET-запросом

Comment: Откройте консоль F12, вкладка Network/Сеть и изучайте свой запрос.

Comment: @vp_arth открыл, посмотрел: `URL запроса: http://127.0.0.1:8000/azmiestsklad/sklad/`. Может есть еще что-то, но во вкладке `Параметры` написано: `В этом запросе нет параметров`

Comment: Там есть всё, посмотрите заголовки, если и там не найдёте, значит не передаётся ничего.

Comment: @vp_arth может ли Django, а конкретно Python скрипт отвечать за скрытие GET-запроса?